# Java Control Panel on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I work with NetBeans 7.4 + Java Update 45 installed on Windows 8.1. I've tried to get to the Java Control Panel, by using the Windows search charm. This does, indeed, lead me to a java icon for the Java Control panel. However, when I click on the icon, something flashes by and then nothing. Does anyone know a work around?

Answer (score 6):

Try running

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javacpl.exe
```

if using 32-bit Java, or

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javacpl.exe
```

if using 64-bit Java.  You'll need to run them as administrator for the settings to take effect.

Comment: @user3054142: No worries.  That's how you run the Java Control Panel on Windows 7 as well if you want the changes you make to take effect - if you launch the Java Control Panel from the Windows 7 Control Panel, the `javacpl.exe` process won't be run as administrator and the changes you make won't take effect.