# java console window not appearing

Tags: java, windows-8, console

When starting a Java program e.g.

```
  Java -cp path/to/ main.class
```

my application starts, but I don't get a console in Win 8.1. I have [set the Java console Switch to show console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398289/java-control-panel-on-windows-8-1) as Admin. But the console still doesn't show up.

Comment: If you are showing the console as an admin it might be because you need to enter the username and password

Comment: @man-qa: For understanding: I started the javacpl.exe from a command prompt that I started as admin. There I had to use the admin username&password. The Java app itself user. I tried also to start the app as admin.

Comment: No solution so far? I currently can reproduce this under fully patched Windows 7 with current Java 8, too.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Console is available for applets running with Java Plug-in and applications running with Java Web Start.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/console_trace_log.html

If you are running your command from a command interpreter, it will become your console for input and output unless otherwise redirected. If you are using javaw you will have no console.

Answer (score -5):

Bring up the Windows Charms bar through Windows key + W. Search for "Java Control Panel" and open that up. Go into the "Advanced" tab and the second category down should be "Java Console" - make sure that the "Show Console" option is selected.

Comment: The option is selected and the window is not appearing. This is exactly what the link in my question is about. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398289/java-control-panel-on-windows-8-1)